# How to use angular as frontend with laravel on existing project

Tags: angular, laravel

I have a laravel project already running , and also new angular project which is only a new shape ,I need to use this angular project instead if current old blade files so angular will be frontend and laravel backend , How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop api end points in the existing laravel project. Also session will not work in this mode and token will be used instead to manage user's authorization. You can google jwt in laravel for more information.
Then the connection between Angular client and Laravel will be created by sending ajax requests to the backend.

Comment: Okay , and where angular files will be ?

Comment: It will be in a separate directory. imaging you have two separate cores, one for Laravel and one for Angular. they make communication by using ajax.